# Gtk-ERROR in Python

Tags: python, gtk

I tried to install this tool called **pycontact** from [Pycontact](https://github.com/maxscheurer/pycontact) today at my Uni's server, but after installation, it's fetching me this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib-2.2.0rc1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py:32: DeprecationWarning: Gdk.Cursor.new is deprecated
cursors.MOVE          : Gdk.Cursor.new(Gdk.CursorType.FLEUR),
(pycontact:3296): Gtk-ERROR **: GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

It seeems like there is an issue with Nvidia's graphics card or sort of. Is there any way we can sort out this problem

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the software is trying to mix Gtk2 and Gtk3 which is not supported. I would contact the developers.

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see the relation between pycontact and your problem. Pycontact uses the Qt toolkit (version 5), not GTK+.

The problem is within your mathplotlib script, which uses GTK+ 3 I suppose, since it's named `backend_gtk3.py`. Somewhere, in the same process, GTK+ components are used and this is not supported as sais in the error message you received:

> Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported